# Does app data hide files or create a virtual folder?

Tags: windows, appdata

My application creates a bunch of temporary .class files and I had been storing these files in my local application directory but I recently started storing these in appData.  Everything functions fine and I even have a part of my application that creates an applet and needs to copy these .class files to make the applet and the applet works fine but for some reason the .class files are not showing up in AppData.  I searched for the .class files (with everything enables hidden files et al) and the only place they show up are in the applet I created.  This seems impossible that this could be happening unless somehow things stored in AppData are hidden or there is some sort of virtual folder at work here.  I have tried this on both XP and windows seven.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your application spit out (debug print, message box, however) the absolute path to where it is writing the files.

Windows XP search function is rather crippled by default and it will not find files in many locations including folders that it considers temporary, hidden, system or non indexed, as well as several specific folders in the user profile.

A quick way to do a 'useful' search is from the command line from within your profile directory:

```
dir /s /b | find ".class"
```

Answer (score 0):

No virtual folder or hiding going on that I know of.  Have you verified the AppData location on your machine?  WindowsKey-R (or Start -> Run) then type %appdata% and see what comes up.